# pip install can't find a package - gone from PyPi

Tags: django, ubuntu-12.04, virtualenv, pip

I'm writing a bash script to setup a freshly installed Ubuntu VM as a development and testing machine with Django and gUnicorn in a virtual environment. It successfully installs packages with apt-get, but then when I run pip recursively against the requirements.txt file, it cannot find any of the packages. I tried manually activating the virtual environment and running 
    pip install ==
This worked fine, and pip started saying Django was already installed, but then failed with the others. I tried --pre and --no-index to no avail. --no-index does, however, get rid of an incredibly huge (3000+ line) Traceback it had been printing.

Here is the script:

```
# VARIABLES
# none for now

# COLORED OUTPUT
function echo_green {
    tput setaf 2
    echo $1
    tput sgr0
}

function echo_yellow {
    tput setaf 3
    echo $1
    tput sgr0
}
function echo_red {
    tput setaf 1
    echo "Important Note: $1"
    tput sgr0
}
function echo_blue {
    tput setaf 4
    echo $1
    tput sgr0
}

# TODO: Create output like script <filename> ran on <date>
# TODO: Have output go to file as well as stdout

# GLOBAL PACKAGES
echo_green 'Doing System level installs'
echo_green 'Using sudo'
# ubuntu and debian have apt-get
echo_green 'vim'
sudo apt-get install vim
echo_green 'tmux'
sudo apt-get install tmux
echo_green 'pip'
sudo apt-get install python-pip
echo_green 'virtualenv'
sudo easy_install virtualenv
echo_green 'git'
sudo apt-get install git

# CLONE REPO
echo_yellow "Working as user: `whoami`"
echo_yellow "working in `pwd`"
echo_yellow "cloning Services repo"
git clone <our repo>

# CREATE VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT
# hard coding file names to simplify discussion between devs referring to certain directories and files
mkdir Environment
echo 'Environment/' >> .gitignore
virtualenv Environment
echo_blue "Activating virtual environment"
source ./Environment/bin/activate
echo_green 'Installing distribute in virtual env'
sudo easy_install 'distribute==0.6.28'
echo_yellow "If pip tries to install a specific version of something, this can be a mess if it's already installed. Use pip uninstall first. Do not install with anything but pip if possible. Use pip in virtual env. Anything else has potential for mess making and bug hiding."
# TODO: make sure python is v 2.7.5
# Note the lack of sudo. This is related to virtualenv. We're not doing this globally.
 # pip install --upgrade pip
easy_install --upgrade pip
pip install -r ./Services/requirements.txt --pre # --no-index might solve some errors

# mysqlclient-dev

# mysql server?

# then put the dump into it
```

Error I get:

> Using
>   /home/bret/Work/Environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg
>   Processing dependencies for pip Finished processing dependencies for
>   pip Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/ Requirement
>   already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Django==1.5.1 in
>   ./Environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r
>   ./Services/requirements.txt (line 1)) Downloading/unpacking
>   Fabric==1.7.0 (from -r ./Services/requirements.txt (line 2))   Could
>   not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement Fabric==1.7.0
>   (from -r ./Services/requirements.txt (line 2)) Cleaning up... No
>   distributions at all found for Fabric==1.7.0 (from -r
>   ./Services/requirements.txt (line 2)) Storing debug log for failure in
>   /home/bret/.pip/pip.log

A couple clues:

```
pip install "Django==1.5.1"
pip install "distribute==0.6.28"
cat Services/requirements.txt | sed '/distribute/d' | sed '/distribute/d' > .requirements_tmp.txt
pip install -r .requirements_tmp.txt --use-mirrors --pre  --no-index #might solve some errors
rm .requirements_tmp.txt
```

This works for the packages explicitly given their own line. It uses sed to remove them from a temporary copy of requirements, which pip is then run against. For some reason the use of -r is causeing pip not to find anything

I have already tried flags:
--pre
--no-index
--use-mirrors

I also tried updating and upgrading Ubuntu

Comment: Can yo make that little bit more readable?

Comment: What about it is unreadable? The question, the script, the error?

Comment: Sorry, the question did not orignally format for me well. Reading it again now.

Comment: Also make sure you do not have any case-sensitivity issues (fabric vs. Fabric)

Comment: I think Fabric==1.7.0 might have actually been removed from the archive for some reason. It's making the HTTP requests but they're getting a 404. I think I'll have to either use different versions or host a private index. I'm still not sure why some of them work in their own line (without -r requirements.txt).

Comment: The first rule of PyPi is that never remove packages from there. However many developers do not respect this.

Comment: Yep that's what happened. I basically took it as a given that nothing would be gone from the archive so it took a while to really dawn on me.

Comment: Ok let me edit my answer, maybe you can mark it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that

- The package actually exist and is not removed (first rule of PyPi is that never remove packages). See simple index https://pypi.python.org/simple/
- There is no system-wide package which version conflicts with virtualenv without `--no-site-packages`.
- There is no case-sensitivity issues with the package name

Comment: I tried installing distribute system wide to try to overcome these errors but I'm getting the same errors I got before I added that line.

Comment: I had to recompile my recent Python with libbz2-dev to support bz2 compressed releases of PyPI packages.